# writing a script to import json on column based off of another cell value

Tags: google-apps-script, import, google-sheets

I have built a tracker that tracks the status of where the package is at, however, the tracker has grown substantially and it's become tiring to keep adding the formula to each cell and also seems to be lagging the sheet.

Is there a way to write a script that automatically does this based on the value of another cell.

Example:

```
=IF(A1<>"",importjson(join("","https://shipit.herokuapp.com/api/carriers/",C1,"/",A1),"activities/0/details"),"")
```

A1 is the tracking number and C1 is the carrier name. This formula would sit in B1 which would then give the result of the shipping status, based on the information from A1 and C1.

Comment: You might be able to access them [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)

Comment: Welcome. Please share your spreadsheet, and show the location of the formula and the variables that you are trying to build into the formula.